# Need large amount of road distances

Tags: database, distance, relationships

I am working on a travel guide like project and need to connect destinations between each other. The database will contain thousands of locations and need to calculate road distances between them (or get them from some source).

What would be the best way to collect this kind of information (keeping in mind that there are a lot of connections to be made, and plan to add even more).

I tried Google's direction API but I just keep hitting query limits after a short while. This API is probably not for this purpose.

Any advice?

Comment: Download the [OSM](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) dataset?

Comment: Can i use that whit my php project? How can i read the data from it to store it in database?

Comment: You may have to code in some other language to prepare the data, but at least you got it all there.